# SQL Server Create Table Variable to hold records which will be inserted into permanent Table after truncating permanent table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with around 7 million rows which I need to perform a truncate of the table. I am going to do this like the following:

```
BEGIN TRY

BEGIN TRANSACTION

Declare @RecsToKeep Table
 (
    Id int
 )
 SELECT Id
        FROM RealTable
     Where CONVERT (DATE, CreatedDate) > '2017-08-16'


Declare @KeepTheseRecs Table
 (
    Id int
 )

 Insert into @KeepTheseRecs
   Select *
     From RealTable Where Id IN (Select Id From @RecsToKeep)

Truncate Table RealTable

Insert into RealTable
 Select *
   From @KeepTheseRecs

COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

The real table and table variable have the same column structure. Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: What happens if your insert fails and you lose the data? Seems dangerous without at least a transaction. I think an audit table is worth a consideration.

Answer (score 0):

First, you haven't changed anything in the table based off your query. You are simply moving the records from A to B and back to A.

A simpler method would be to skip the move all together.

```
delete from RealTable
where someColumn = 'someValue' --or what ever condition you want
```

If you are really going to stage the records, you're going to at least want a `WHERE` clause on that `Insert Into` statement. I really don't see why you need to do this though.